# maximum eigenvalue of a diagonal plus rank-one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to compute the maximum eigenvalue of a diagonal plus rank-one matrix. Are there fast algorithms for the computation of the largest eigenvalue? What is the computational complexity of those algorithms?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration)?  This is the simplest way to approximate the dominant eigenvalue, requiring a simple sequence of matrix-vector multiplications (with scaling as needed to keep the results within a range of floating point exponents).  Here you have the advantage of doing the matrix-vector multiplies with $O(n)$ arithmetic in each step.

Comment: I am familiar with the power method, but I think that the special structure can be exploited somehow. I guess that this structure may have been considered before in the literature.

Comment: A normal (dense) matrix-vector multiply is $O(n^2)$, so you would be exploiting the special structure of your matrix by reducing this operation cost to $O(n)$.  If you are hoping the special form allows you to solve directly for eigenvalues, I do not think what you've described so far allows this.

Comment: Here's another request: Are your diagonal-plus-rank-one matrices symmetric?  I assumed not since you didn't specify, but it makes things a bit easier if they were symmetric.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numerical eigenvalue problem for diagonal-plus-rank-one (DPR1) matrices has been considered in the literature, often in a broader context of algorithms for [generalized companion matrices](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829163204/http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/%7Ercorless/frames/PAPERS/PABV/CMP.pdf).

Typical of these is the recent paper "Accurate eigenvalue decomposition of arrowhead matrices and applications," by [N.J. Stor, I. Slapnicara, J. Barlow (arXiv.org, 2013)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.7203v3.pdf), cf. Sec. 6.3 where the real-symmetric DPR1 eigenvalue problem for $D + uu^T$ is treated (and according to *Remark 5* a more general such case is the subject of a ["forthcoming paper"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7537)).

Slightly older but perhaps more germane (by treating the nonsymmetric case) is the paper "Fast and Stable QR eigenvalue algorithms for generalized companion matrices and secular equations," by [Bini, Gemignani, and Pan, *Numer. Math.* (2005)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506205255/http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/vpan/pdf/209.pdf), which gives details of an $O(n^2)$ operation, $O(n)$ space method for finding all eigenvalues to high relative precision by a structure preserving variant of QR steps.

As noted in my Comments above, a [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) for determining a dominant eigenvalue can take advantage of the special structure of DPR1 matrices in forming matrix-vector products with $O(n)$ operation cost, a significant improvement over the usual $O(n^2)$ cost for matrix-vector products.

This advantage carries over to more sophisticated algorithms which accelerate convergence (by shift & invert) or which improve stability via orthogonal transforms (as with QR; see above).  Note that the shift of a DPR1 matrix is DPR1, and the inverse of an invertible DPR1 matrix [is again DPR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

**Added:** In the special case $D=I$ the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $I + vu^T$ can be explicitly expressed, just as a spectrum shift for rank one matrix $vu^T$.  That is, $(I+vu^T)u = (v\cdot u + 1) u$, and for any $w\cdot u = 0$, then $(I+uv^T)w = w$.  The largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ is then $v\cdot u + 1$ or $1$ depending on the sign of $v\cdot u$.

Standard treatments of [estimating the largest eigenvalue of a positive definite symmetric matrix](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-38-157/S0025-5718-1982-0637293-9/S0025-5718-1982-0637293-9.pdf) often begin with a reduction to tridiagonal form, either by full similarity transformation or by a Lanczos type approximation of smaller dimension.  Because the DPR1 structure is already of $O(n)$ size, there is no need for tridiagonal reduction, and instead one can immediately begin searching for the largest eigenvalue (at least in the symmetric case) through evaluations of $\det(\lambda I - (D+uu^T))$.

Provided $\lambda$ differs from any of the entries on diagonal $D$, $\lambda I - D$ is invertible/has nonzero determinant and can be factored out, leaving us with evaluation of $\det(I - wu^T)$ where $w = (\lambda I - D)^{-1} u$.  The material discussed in the first added paragraph above can be recast as an explicit characteristic polynomial, and in particular, if $w\cdot u \neq 0$:

$$ \det(I - wu^T) = 1 - w\cdot u $$

whose evaluation has cost $O(n)$.

Comment: The diagonal matrix D is not the identity and, in general, the entries of the diagonal are all different.

Comment: Not everything I added above depends on $D$ being the identity, as for example the evaluation of the determinant can be done in $O(n)$ without assuming anything other than $D$ invertible.  Is the matrix symmetric?  Positive definite?

Comment: The matrix D is positive definite

Comment: Okay, the diagonal part is positive definite (symmetric), but the  rank one part is not necessarily symmetric (and the combination is not necesssarily positive definite symmetric)?

Comment: The matrix is of the type D + uu'

Comment: @Caiyou:  Your proposed changes are not for "type errors". I intentionally wrote the scalar values $v\cdot u$ and similar to make it evident (because the dot product gives a scalar) which factors are scalars rather than matrices $vu^T$.