# How can I estimate the solution with largest modulus of $1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i - \lambda}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to estimate the largest solution (the solution with largest modulus) of the equation
$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i - \lambda},$$
where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are known, and $\lambda$ is the unknown. All variables are complex.

In the case where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real and all of the same sign, an acceptable estimate would be $\max_i \lvert b_i - a_i \rvert$. The generalization to complex numbers is not so clear, or not even the generalization to the case where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real numbers with varying sign.

It would of course be possible to convert the problem to finding the largest root of an $n$-th order polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$, but I don't think this would make the problem any easier.

The equation arises from trying to find the largest eigenvalue of a matrix $A - B$, where $A = \operatorname{diag}(a)$, $a = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$, and
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
&&\vdots \\
b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Just an idea (maybe useless): It could be that the polynomial (after conversion) is the characteristic polynomial of a normal nxn matrix. If so, the problem reduces to estimating the spectral norm of it. You can also have a look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots

Comment: Thank you, you are actually quite close to the problem where the equation came from. I have added some more detail in the question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix may be very relevant.