# low rank approximations and diagonalization

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

I would like to discuss or hear an opinion about the following. Given is the (hermitian) $n\times n$ matrix

$A = D+M V M^{\dagger}$

with D diagonal. I would like to calculate the eigenvalues (and vectors) of $A$ as economically as possible.
What I would normally apply here is a Lanczos type of algorithm which (as far as I know) does at least not scale as $\mathcal{O} (n^3)$.

First of all do you think a procedure as follows can outperform this?

1. low rank approximation of $M V M^{\dagger}$
2. use algorithm for diagonalization of a  diagonal + low rank matrix

As far as 2. goes I know there exist algorithms which deal with diagonal + rank 1 matrices very efficiently (as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix)). 
This for me is an incentive to believe that low rank could simplify the calculation of eigenvalues. However I don't know if this extends to any other but rank 1 matrices.

For 1. there is [this](http://thanglong.ece.jhu.edu/Tran/Pub/Nam_LRMA_STOC.pdf) paper I found that gives a low rank approximation without the need of SVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If V has rank k for small k, then the cheapest way to find spectrum of A is to apply rank 1 update procedure k times.

If k is not small, then the structure of A will not help to speed up direct eigensolvers (like divide-and-conquer or QR).

If only few eigenvalues are required, then the Lanczos algorithm will be the fastest. Low rank approximation of $MVM'$ will not help much. It may save some time in forming matrix-vector products $A x$ required by the Lanczos algorithm, but will disturb eigenvalues substantially.