# Approximating a matrix with $ACA^t$ with known $A$

Tags: matrices, optimization, approximation, svd

Let $X$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $A$ be $n \times m$ matrix and . $A$ is not related to $X$.
Suppose we know there is an approximation 
$X \approx ACA^t$ where $C$ is $m\times m$ matrix ($m < n$).

Can we efficiently find $C$ ?
(Without solving large optimization problem)

Can we do this efficiently if we know $C$ is sparse or diagonal ?

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826093/low-rank-approximations-and-diagonalization) question I know there is no general connection between a general matrix $C$ and the eigenvalues of $X$, but what if we know $C$ is diagonal ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $X$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes, $X$ is symmetric. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ has rank $m$. Then $A^t A$ is invertible, and  $$C \approx (A^t A)^{-1} A^t X A (A^t A)^{-1}$$

More generally, consider $\tilde{C} = A^+ X {A^+}^t$ where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$.  If $X = A C A^t$, then 
$$A \tilde{C} A^t = A A^+ A C A^t {A^+}^t A^t = A C A^t = X$$