# eigenvalues of "diagonal matrix $+$ rank one matrix"

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

I am confused about the following claim:

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$v = \begin{cases}
1 & i \text{-th entry}\\
-1 & j \text{-th entry} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Let $\Lambda\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a diagonal matrix.

We know that $vv^T$ is rank one, so only one nonzero eigenvalue (actually it is $2$ in my case.)

> Will $\Lambda + vv^T$ only increase one eigenvalue of $\Lambda$?

I do not believe this is correct and it can be checked by Matlab.

> Is there any extra conditions or related theorem for changing only one eigenvalue of a diagonal matrix by adding a specific matrix (such as rank one)?

Comment: If it's rank $1$ with just the $(1,1)$ entry nonzero and everything else zero then we get the desired result, but this is trivial. I can't think of a really general case immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum eigenvalue of a diagonal plus rank-one matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix)

Comment: [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) applies to this situation.  I'm pretty sure that in your particular case, two eigenvalues will change since $v$ lies in the span of two eigenvectors of (possibly) distinct eigenvalues.  The eigenvalues outside of the $i$th and $j$th, however, will remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I state in my comment, [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) tell you everything you can say using only the length of $v$.

We can clearly see through an example that, in general, more than one eigenvalue will change.  For example: the matrix
$$
\Lambda = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.  However, 
$$
\Lambda + vv^T = \pmatrix{2 & -1\\-1 & 1}
$$
has eigenvalues $\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, which means that both eigenvalues have changed.

It is notable, however, that for your friend's choice of $v$, only the $i$th and $j$th eigenvalues from the diagonal might change.  If $v$ is an eigenvector of $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda$ is symmetric, then $\Lambda + vv^T$ will have the same eigenvectors as $\Lambda$ and only the eigenvalue corresponding to $v$ will change.