# Is it possible to characterize the changes in eigenvalues of a diagonal plus rank-1 matrix from eigenvalue gaps?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

**Problem:** 
Let $M = D + \sigma uu^\top$, where $D$ is a positive semidefinite diagonal matrix, in particular, $0 = d_1 < d_2 \leq d_3 \leq \ldots \leq d_n$ and $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_i)$. Also, let's consider $\sigma > 0$. Finally, let $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $M$.

I am interested in a non-trivial lower bound for $\lambda_2$, but if there are more general results then those are welcome too.

**Research:**
I was doing some research on this problem, and found Weyl's inequality, and some other related questions like these:

[1] [eigenvalues of "diagonal matrix $+$ rank one matrix"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776041/eigenvalues-of-diagonal-matrix-rank-one-matrix)

[2] [maximum eigenvalue of a diagonal plus rank-one matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix)

I could find that in general $d_i \leq \lambda_i$. However, I noticed the following by running some experiments on MATLAB: when $d_i = d_{i+1}$, then $\lambda_i = d_i$, i.e., the eigenvalue is not changed; but when $d_i < d_{i+1}$ then $d_i < \lambda_i$, i.e., the eigenvalue increases. I was wondering if one could get a lower bound like this $d_i + \epsilon_i \leq \lambda_i$ whenever $d_i<d_{i+1}$. My intuition was that maybe $\epsilon_i$ is related to the gap $(d_{i+1} - d_i)$ and the $\ell_2$-norm of $u$ but I was not able to get something.

Comment: Weyl's inequality is the best you can do.  In particular, the fact that $D$ is constrained to be positive semidefinite and diagonal (as opposed to $D$ simply being symmetric) does not change the answer.

Comment: Do you have a formal statement of why Weyl's inequality is the best I can do? Note that in my question I'm interested in the case that $d_i < \lambda_i$ (strict inequality) which appears to happen whenever $d_i < d_{i+1}$. That's why I was thinking that maybe one can obtain a tighter bound in those cases. My comment about the possible relation to eigenvalue gaps was because when $d_{i+1} - d_i \approx 0$ then $\lambda_i \approx d_i$ which is equality when $d_{i+1} = d_{i}$. It'd help me a lot to maybe see why we cannot hope for a tighter bound (in that particular case). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Note that for any symmetric matrix $M$, $D = VMV^T$ is diagonal for some orthogonal matrix $V$, by the spectral theorem.  It follows that $M + uu^T$ has the same eigenvalues as the similar matrix
$$
V(M + \sigma uu^T)V^T = VMV^T + \sigma (Vu)(Vu)^T = D + \sigma vv^T.
$$
In other words, we can always reduce our consideration to the case where $M$ is symmetric.  Also, note that adding a large enough multiple of the identity to $D$ can make $D$ positive definite without changing the eigenvalue gaps.  So, we can reduce our consideration to positive definite $D$.

Comment: Just to make sure I explained myself correctly. I was referring to the change of eigenvalues of $D$ to those of $M$. Stated in "another way", since $d_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are the $i$-th eigenvalues of $D$ and $M$ respectively, I was curious to know whether there is a characterization of $\epsilon >0$ such that $\epsilon < \lambda_i - d_i$ when $d_i < d_{i+1}$. I'm sorry I'm still not clear how your last comment solves this question, any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say with the $\epsilon$'s in either your post or in your comment. As far as your lower bound for $\lambda_2$ goes, the bound $\lambda_2 \geq d_2$ is sharp.